# Hot Network Questions MathJax

Tags: bug, design, hot-questions, mathjax

I discovered an interesting bug in the HNQ list just now.

The title of a Money SE question is [Getting $10,000 and have $16,000 balance on two credit cards - How to allocate payments?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/70601/getting-10-000-have-16-000-balance-on-two-credit-cards-how-to-allocate-paym).  It displays in the HNQ list incorrectly, however; notice how part of it is italicized, and the dollar signs are not displayed:

[image: HNQ image]

Comment: [i'm not getting it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lTgnJ.png) on Chrome 53.0.2785.101 m on Windows 7

Comment: What's your browser? No repro on Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m on Win10

Comment: Reproduced by seeing that question on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm on IceDragon (FF's rendering engine).

Comment: [confirmed what @Pang said on Chrome 53.0.2785.101 m on Windows 7](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Wba.png) so far it seems to only affect math.se. though trying to get it to appear is a pain (i had to refresh like 20 times before i got it to appear again). my first screenshot was from meta.se

Comment: I just discovered it does display correctly on WorldBuilding.  Same browser.  I'm pretty sure I was on Puzzling the first time I saw it.  Update: it's fine on Puzzling.

Comment: doesn't occur on [biology](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LSJKz.png) which is listed as being one of the sites with mathjax (only had to refresh 5 times that time)